# Laravel 5.4 hasMany belongsTo not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to reference a relationship in a blade foreach statement as

```
@foreach($customer->invoices as $invoice)
```

The error I am receiving is `Undefined property: stdClass::$invoices (View: ...\customerView.blade.php)`.

Here is the code for the Customer and Invoice models

Customer

```
class Customer extends Model
{
   public function invoices()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Invoice');
   }
}
```

Invoice

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
   public function customer()
   {
      $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
   }
}
```

And here is the database migration files for both.

Customer

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('firstName');
   $table->string('lastName');
   $table->string('phoneNumber');
   $table->string('email');
});
```

Invoice

```
Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('customer_id');
   $table->integer('item_id');
   $table->date('dateCreated');
   $table->string('balance');
   $table->string('status');
});
```

Is anyone able to see what I am missing?

Revelant Controller Code:

```
public function view($id)
{
    $customer = DB::table('customers')->where('id', $id)->first();

    return view('pages.customer.customerView', compact('customer'));
}
```

Comment: add your controller and view files

Comment: Everything looks correct at a glance, can you show the code that defines `$customer`? `$customer->invoices` shouldn't throw that error if `$customer` is a `Model`. I.e. if `$customer = \App\Customer::first(); dd($customer->bs_property)` should be `null`, not an exception.

Comment: Show us the way you initialized `$customer` object.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QWnE9e6f  https://pastebin.com/dPph5hy5   https://pastebin.com/dCtS847s

There's the code for the model and the customer as well as the customer controller

Comment: In the future, please edit your code when requested; pastebin links are fine, but more work for us.

Comment: To be more concise, here's the code in the controller that loads the blade file.

    public function view($id)
    {
        $customer = DB::table('customers')->where('id', $id)->first();

        return view('pages.customer.customerView', compact('customer'));
    }

Comment: Sorry mate, brand new didn't realize.

Comment: No worries; I can edit, but not all users can, so if someone with less rep was the only one helping, it would be stuck in the comments :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how you're using `DB::table("customers")` in `public function view()`? Your relationships are defined on the model `Customer`, not on the `DB` facade, so you code should be:

```
public function view($id)
{
    $customer = \App\Customer::where('id', $id)->first();

    return view('pages.customer.customerView', compact('customer'));
}
```

Comment: You have it right almost everywhere else (create, edit, etc), just make sure to not use `DB::table()` if you have a model defined (check your `public function index()` method as well)